# Looping through JSON Data with pure JavaScript to populate a specified number of articles in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax, api

**Please find code below following my explanation and questions:**

I am using myjson.com to generate 12 'results'. These 'results' consist of 12 clients all of which have different bits of data associated. For example,

Client 1:
First Name - James,

Address - 1234 Maple Street

Client 2:
First Name - Jack,

Address - 4321 Lorem Ipsum Lane

My Question:
How do I populate the following 12 articles in HTML with the JSON Data using a For Loop with my JavaScript and Ajax Request?

```
    <article>
        <img class="photo" height="100" width="100">
        <hgroup>
            <h1 class="name"></h1>
            <h2 class="email"></h2>
        </hgroup>
    </article>

    <article>
        <img class="photo" height="100" width="100">
        <hgroup>
            <h1 class="name"></h1>
            <h2 class="email"></h2>
        </hgroup>
    </article>

    <article>
        <img class="photo" height="100" width="100">
        <hgroup>
            <h1 class="name"></h1>
            <h2 class="email"></h2>
        </hgroup>
    </article>

    <article>
        <img class="photo" height="100" width="100">
        <hgroup>
            <h1 class="name"></h1>
            <h2 class="email"></h2>
        </hgroup>
    </article>

    <article>
        <img class="photo" height="100" width="100">
        <hgroup>
            <h1 class="name"></h1>
            <h2 class="email"></h2>
        </hgroup>
    </article>

    <article>
        <img class="photo" height="100" width="100">
        <hgroup>
            <h1 class="name"></h1>
            <h2 class="email"></h2>
        </hgroup>
    </article>

    <article>
        <img class="photo" height="100" width="100">
        <hgroup>
            <h1 class="name"></h1>
            <h2 class="email"></h2>
        </hgroup>
    </article>
    <article>
        <img class="photo" height="100" width="100">
        <hgroup>
            <h1 class="name"></h1>
            <h2 class="email"></h2>
        </hgroup>
    </article>

    <article>
        <img class="photo" height="100" width="100">
        <hgroup>
            <h1 class="name"></h1>
            <h2 class="email"></h2>
        </hgroup>
    </article>

    <article>
        <img class="photo" height="100" width="100">
        <hgroup>
            <h1 class="name"></h1>
            <h2 class="email"></h2>
        </hgroup>
    </article>

    <article>
        <img class="photo" height="100" width="100">
        <hgroup>
            <h1 class="name"></h1>
            <h2 class="email"></h2>
        </hgroup>
    </article>

    <article>
        <img class="photo" height="100" width="100">
        <hgroup>
            <h1 class="name"></h1>
            <h2 class="email"></h2>
        </hgroup>
    </article>*



`    const Employees = (function () {


let displayStudent = document.querySelector('.photo');
let name = document.querySelector('.name');
let email = document.querySelector('.email');
let phone = document.querySelector('.phone');
let streetAddress = document.querySelector('.streetAddress');
let city = document.querySelector('.city');
let state = document.querySelector('.state');
let zip = document.querySelector('.zip');

const ajaxCall = function () {
    let hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    let url = 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/zfhmr'; //https://randomuser.me/api/
    // myjson.com
    hr.onreadystatechange = function () {

        if (hr.readyState === 4) { //ajax is complete
            if (hr.status === 200) { //successful network exchange

                let myObj = JSON.parse(hr.responseText);   
                for(let i = 0; i < myObj.length; i++) {
                displayStudent.src = myObj.results[0].picture.large;
                name.innerHTML = myObj.results[0].name.first + " " + myObj.results[0].name.last;
                }
                console.log(myObj[i]);

                /*
                email.innerHTML = myObj.results[0].email;
                phone.innerHTML = myObj.results[0].phone;
                streetAddress.innerHTML = myObj.results[0].location.street;
                city.innerHTML = myObj.results[0].location.city;
                state.innerHTML = myObj.results[0].location.state;
                zip.innerHTML = myObj.results[0].location.postcode;
                */



            }
        } else {
            console.log("ajax error: " + hr.response);
        }
    };

    hr.open("GET", url, true);
    hr.send();

    console.log(hr);


};
return {
    init: function () {
        ajaxCall();
    }
};

}());

Employees.init();    `
```

I am having trouble with populating more than ONE article with just one client at the time. Any help is much appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: you have two clients rows and you want to populate the 12 articles first with one client and then with the other or 6 with one client and 6 with the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see something weird in your code example when I check with your `JSON` response.

Your `json` response looks like this...

```
{
    "results": [...]
}
```

Your for loop looks like this...

```
let myObj = JSON.parse(hr.responseText);
for(let i = 0; i < myObj.length; i++) {
    displayStudent.src = myObj.results[0].picture.large;
    name.innerHTML = myObj.results[0].name.first + " " + 
    myObj.results[0].name.last;
}
```

- So in your code, you're trying to loop an object (which does not even contain a `.length` property), in this case `myObj` is not an array list.
- And `myObj.results[0]` always returns the first result.

**Solution**

You should dynamically inject the `html` elements in your `for` loop.

```
<!-- In your HTML file -->
<div id="articleContainer"></div>
```

```
// In your javascript ajax response (success)
if (hr.readyState === 4 && hr.status === 200) { // ajax is complete and successful network exchange
    let container = document.querySelector('#articleContainer');
    let strArticles = "";

    let myObj = JSON.parse(hr.responseText);
    for(let i = 0; i < myObj.results.length; i++) {
        let resObj = myObj.results[i];

        strArticles += '<article>' +
                            '<img class="photo" src="' + resObj.picture.large + '" height="100" width="100">' +
                            '<hgroup>' +
                                '<h1 class="name">' + resObj.name.first + ' ' + name.last + '</h1>' +
                                '<h2 class="email">' + resObj.email + '</h2>' +
                            '</hgroup>' +
                        '</article>';
    }

    // Inject the string html into the container parent element.
    container.innerHTML = strArticles;
}
```

Hope this works out for you :)

Comment: This works very well. You saved me many nights of frustration. The one correction I made was regarding the last name. I inserted "resObj.name.last" to generate the last name. Otherwise everything functions correctly!

Comment: You're welcome :) Oops, yeah, you're right. Silly mistake :P

Answer (score 0):

Your 'i' variable was out of the scope of your for loop, and do not nest if statements. Also if you are trying to populate repeating HTML snippets with data, you might want to consider using a template and spitting that out instead of querying all the individual elements with selectors.

```js
const Employees = (function() {
  let displayStudent = document.querySelector('.photo');
  let name = document.querySelector('.name');
  let email = document.querySelector('.email');
  let phone = document.querySelector('.phone');
  let streetAddress = document.querySelector('.streetAddress');
  let city = document.querySelector('.city');
  let state = document.querySelector('.state');
  let zip = document.querySelector('.zip');

  const ajaxCall = function() {
    let hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    let url = 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/zfhmr'; //https://randomuser.me/api/
    // myjson.com
    hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (hr.readyState === 4 && hr.status === 200) { //ajax is complete
        //successful network exchange

        let myObj = JSON.parse(hr.responseText);
        for (let i = 0; i < myObj.length; i++) {
          displayStudent.src = myObj.results[0].picture.large;
          name.innerHTML = myObj.results[0].name.first + " " + myObj.results[0].name.last;

          console.log(myObj[i]);

          /*
          email.innerHTML = myObj.results[0].email;
          phone.innerHTML = myObj.results[0].phone;
          streetAddress.innerHTML = myObj.results[0].location.street;
          city.innerHTML = myObj.results[0].location.city;
          state.innerHTML = myObj.results[0].location.state;
          zip.innerHTML = myObj.results[0].location.postcode;
          */


        }

      } else {
        console.log("ajax error: " + hr.response);
      }
    };

    hr.open("GET", url, true);
    hr.send();

    console.log(hr);


  };
  return {
    init: function() {
      ajaxCall();
    }
  };

})();

Employees.init();
```

```html
<article>
  <img class="photo" height="100" width="100">
  <hgroup>
    <h1 class="name"></h1>
    <h2 class="email"></h2>
  </hgroup>
</article>

<article>
  <img class="photo" height="100" width="100">
  <hgroup>
    <h1 class="name"></h1>
    <h2 class="email"></h2>
  </hgroup>
</article>

<article>
  <img class="photo" height="100" width="100">
  <hgroup>
    <h1 class="name"></h1>
    <h2 class="email"></h2>
  </hgroup>
</article>

<article>
  <img class="photo" height="100" width="100">
  <hgroup>
    <h1 class="name"></h1>
    <h2 class="email"></h2>
  </hgroup>
</article>

<article>
  <img class="photo" height="100" width="100">
  <hgroup>
    <h1 class="name"></h1>
    <h2 class="email"></h2>
  </hgroup>
</article>

<article>
  <img class="photo" height="100" width="100">
  <hgroup>
    <h1 class="name"></h1>
    <h2 class="email"></h2>
  </hgroup>
</article>

<article>
  <img class="photo" height="100" width="100">
  <hgroup>
    <h1 class="name"></h1>
    <h2 class="email"></h2>
  </hgroup>
</article>
<article>
  <img class="photo" height="100" width="100">
  <hgroup>
    <h1 class="name"></h1>
    <h2 class="email"></h2>
  </hgroup>
</article>

<article>
  <img class="photo" height="100" width="100">
  <hgroup>
    <h1 class="name"></h1>
    <h2 class="email"></h2>
  </hgroup>
</article>

<article>
  <img class="photo" height="100" width="100">
  <hgroup>
    <h1 class="name"></h1>
    <h2 class="email"></h2>
  </hgroup>
</article>

<article>
  <img class="photo" height="100" width="100">
  <hgroup>
    <h1 class="name"></h1>
    <h2 class="email"></h2>
  </hgroup>
</article>

<article>
  <img class="photo" height="100" width="100">
  <hgroup>
    <h1 class="name"></h1>
    <h2 class="email"></h2>
  </hgroup>
</article>
```

An enxample would be:

```js
// blah blah blah ajax call blah blah blah fetch, blah blah blah something else that brings me data

//data comes back as something to iter through
var data = [{
  email: 'something'
}, {
  email: 'something2'
}, {
  email: 'blah'
}, {
  email: 'blah2'
}, {
  email: 'blah blah'
}, {
  email: ':o blah'
}]


data.forEach(item => {
  var div = document.createElement('div')
  div.innerHTML = `<div>some fancy box////   ${item.email}   \\\\\\some more facy box</div>`

  document.body.appendChild(div);
})
```

Comment: @JamesCraneLewisIII  let me know if you need any more help or if there is something you do not understand.